# Quiz questions in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, learnr

I am trying to embed quiz questions from learnr package in shiny app. Since [v0.10.0 leanr](https://blog.rstudio.com/2019/12/02/learnr-0-10-0/) quiz questions are mini shiny applications, i thought it would be easy to add it in shiny. Unfortunately it doesn't work (dont load quiz).

```
library(shiny)
library(learnr)

app <- shinyApp(
  
ui <- tagList(
    fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cosmo")),
    navbarPage(
      "appTitle",
      tabPanel("Tutorial", 
               quiz(
                 question("Quiz question",
                          answer("1"),
                          answer("2"),
                          answer("3", correct = TRUE),
                          answer("4"),
                          allow_retry = TRUE
                 )
               )
      )
      )),
  
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

)

runApp(app)
```

Comment: did you solve this problem? Thanks for sharing.